# Should I change my UserProfile table or create other tables to hold additiaonl user info after user login

Tags: python, django, user-profile

In my project, after login, the user have to go through a few process to input their personal particulars, upload some files

Now I have finished the auth process

there are only three fileds in my UserProfile

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #activation_key is used in my account registration process
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=40) 
    #activation link should be only valid for one day       
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField() 


    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.user.username
```

these three fileds are enough to make the auth process works properly.

Initially in my DB design, I use other tables to hold the personal particulars and the files(as I was not ware yet that I am supposed to use the UserProfile to hold additional data for the user). But after going through the auth process and coming across many posts in the stackoverflow, it seems that I should put the data in the UserProfile table.

So my question is,

1. Can UserProfile contain data both for the auth process(e.g. activation_key key_expire_date) and the specific data e.g. name, country, picture ? (now my UserProfile contains only the data for the auth process)
2. In this situation, adding new fields now or create anther table to hold the additional info, which one is the better practice for a Django project?
3. If I add new fields to the UserProfile, would it affect my previous auth functions?(I am a bit concerned about the profile.save() issue..)

Thank you very much for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no issue in adding further fields to your UserProfile object - as long as you don't change the data in the columns used by the auth process then you will be fine.

With regards to whether you should split the users 'auth' data from their other data (name, country etc) is really a design question. If you expect that every users profile will always have both kinds of data, then having them together in one table probably makes sense. However, if a user may have 'auth' data, but not necessarily have the other data at any given time, then it probably makes sense to split them into two tables so that the data sets can be maintained separately.

Comment: Thanks very much for explaining. for the project i am working on, the auth data will always be there in the Userprofile. And after the user successfully activate his account, it is compulsory that the user enter his additional info. In this case, it would better to have them just in the UserProfile table right?

Comment: In that case I would be tempted to split this into two different tables - for example UserAuth containing the auth data, and UserProfile the rest of the data (both having OneToOne relationships to User of course). This way you avoid having to have null fields in your UserProfile table (which is always preferable). Though of course, if it's more convenient to have all the data in a single UserProfile table (with null values for name, country etc until they are populated) I think this is perfectly acceptable too

Comment: one more question, if I split into another table namely,UserProfile for the auth data and PersonalParticulars for the additional data, both with the OneToOne relationship to User. Is there any settings I need to make for the PersonalParticulars table? as for the UserProfile we should set the  AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE in the settings.py

Comment: Personally, I don't think it is necessary to use `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` for either of them unless you are using some framework which requires this functionality (and in Django 1.5 this is deprecated: http://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releases/1.5.html#auth-profile-module)

Comment: I believe you can use a reverse lookup on the one-to-one relationships to get the objects for a given user (`user.userprofile` and `user.personalparticulars`)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32794/discussion-between-mona-and-robjohncox)